# Cannot parse JSON with new AMPscript function to retrieve token -- value is blank

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, security-token

So I've retrieved this json array below frommy api (obviously this is not the real token value), but this is the payload I'm receiving.

```json
{"access_token":"token","expires_in":86400,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

Then I'm trying to parse this with BuildRowsetFromJson below:

```ampscript
SET @Rows = BuildRowsetFromJson(@json, "$.[*]", 1)
SET @Count = RowCount(@Rows) 

FOR @i = 1 TO @Count DO

    SET @Row = ROW(@Rows, @i)
    SET @access_token = FIELD(@Row, "access_token") 

NEXT @i
ELSE
ENDIF
```

Nothing is erroring out and but the access_token field isn't giving me anything. I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding the jsonpath? But I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` is a subscript operator meant for collections (e.g., arrays), but the value for the `access_token` key in your payload is a string literal. The arguments to the function call should be:

```ampscript
BuildRowsetFromJson(@json, "$.access_token", 1)
```

And with only a single column in the rowset, the call to access the field should be:

```ampscript
SET @access_token = FIELD(@Row, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you it works -- Ignore my previous comment!